# Unity 2D Can't get method to run execute completely

Tags: c#, android, mobile, 2d, unity-game-engine

Hey guys so I'm knew to Unity and I've been working on a tutorial for Unity, and transferring it to a mobile platform. I've gotten most of it to work but the problem is one of my method's doesn't seem to execute fully, I have three main codes. One that controls the ship, the second is the code for my bullets (This is where the problem occurs) and the last is just a GameControl for keeping track of the scores (which doesn't seem to keep track of the scores) The code for my ship control is

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class ShipControl : MonoBehaviour {

        public float playerSpeed = 10f;
        public GameControl gameController;
        public GameObject bulletPrefab;
        public float reloadTime = 1f;
        private bool dragging = false;

        private float elapsedTime = 0;



        void Update()
        {
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0); // get first touch since touch count is greater than zero

                if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) 
                {
                    // get the touch position from the screen touch to world point
                    Vector3 touchedPos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 10));
                    // lerp and set the position of the current object to that of the touch, but smoothly over time.
                    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, touchedPos, Time.deltaTime);
                    if (elapsedTime > reloadTime) {
                        Vector3 spawnPos = transform.position;
                        spawnPos += new Vector3 (0, 1.2f, 0);
                        Instantiate (bulletPrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);

                        elapsedTime = 0f;
                    }
                }
            }
                }

        void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
        {
                gameController.PlayerDied ();
        }

    }
```

The shipControl I don't think this code has anything to do with the problem but just in case I posted it, the next code is where the problem seems to occur(?), I'm not sure because It calls on a method from another class. The problem is the first part executes and the enemy hit by the bullet disappears, however, the score isn't updated and the bullet doesn't disappear.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletCode : MonoBehaviour {
    public float speed = 10f;
    private GameControl gameController;

    void Start()
    {
        gameController = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameControl> ();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate (0f, speed * Time.deltaTime, 0f);
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Meteor_0(Clone)") {
            Destroy (other.gameObject);
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem occurs in the OnCollisionEnter2D method, the first command executes, but after that nothing seems to happen, the GameControl code is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameControl : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text scoreText, gameOverText;
    int playerScore = 0;

    public void AddScore()
    {
        playerScore++;
        scoreText.text = playerScore.ToString ();
    }
    public void PlayerDied()
    {
        gameOverText.enabled = true;
        NewGameBtn ();
    }
    void NewGameBtn()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene (4);
    }
}
```

Anything helps, I appreciate you guys reading this and helping me out, thanks for any help.

Comment: The score isn't updated because you never call `AddScore` in your `GameControl`. Also, try running your game and looking at the meteor objects in the scene inspector. do they all have the same tag? (`"Meteor_0(Clone)"`) because you check if they have that tag before executing `Destroy`. the meteor disappearing does not happen because of the code in the bullet, but perhaps because of its own behavior.

Comment: (hint :  i suspect they will be numbered. (Meteor_1(Clone), Meteor_2(Clone) etc. )

Answer (score 0):

There is no call to AddScore, which explain why the score is not updated
You should try adding it:

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Meteor_0(Clone)") {
    gameController.AddScore();
    Destroy (other.gameObject);
    Destroy (gameObject);
}
```

Now regarding the bullet not being destroyed:

- Be sure you don't mix "tag" and "name" (tag is set in the tag field, name is the name of the object in the scene). Meteor_0(Clone) seems like a name
- if the meteor disappear, it seems that your code goes in the if block. You can still check it by addint a debug line `Debug.Log("destroying bullet now")` just before `Destroy (gameObject);`
- Are you sure that all the visuals of your bullet are on the gameobject that has the BulletCode script? Check which object is destory when calling `Destroy (gameObject);`, maybe it's not the one you want

Comment: Glad it worked. Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it helped